# What is the difference between lib and debug/lib created by vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, build

When I Install packages using vcpkg, it creates lib and Debug/lib, in which are the static libraries. but I wonder what is the difference between them, since I can use both of them as the library path in my Visual Studio C++ Project and both ways can build the project successfully...

(I know that in the debug directory, the libs are for debug. But I only add, for example, imgui.lib, to the "Additional Dependencies", and I set debug/lib(which only has imguid.lib) as the library path, the projected also can be built successfully...How does VS know that imguid.lib is the imgui.lib?)

[Root Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AenDh.png)

[lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuFrs.png)

[debug/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbEmR.png)

Comment: A debug lib is (hopefully) compiled with `/D:_DEBUG` and not optimized while a non-debug lib is compiled with `/D:NDEBUG` and optimized. On one hand, it's probably a pain to debug step-wise optimized code (even if debug symbols are available). On the other hand, the definition of `NDEBUG` will exclude any test in any `assert()` which is in the code. That's reasonable for the deployed application but not for debugging.

Comment: _How does VS know that imguid.lib is the imgui.lib_ You have to add `debug/imguid.lib` for your `Debug` config and `imgui.lib` for your `Release` config. Conventions like this (i.e. debug libs in a separate dir. and/or with a suffix `d`) are suitable to automate this, e.g. if `CMake` scripts are used to prepare the VS solution and project files.

Comment: Got that, thank you a lot